# Using groovy script on Katalon to click on row of grid

Tags: html, xpath, groovy, katalon-studio

With groovy script on Katalon, I want to click on first row of grid but it is not working and it shows error (error.png with Option1 mentioned below) in console.

I have tried by targeting different element's xpath of row but it seems click() event is not being recognized. Also, added wait and waitForPresentElement but did not work.

Following are three options I tried so far but none of them worked.

## Groovy on Katalon:

Option 1:

```
WebUiCommonHelper.findWebElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='dgrid-row dgrid-row-even ui-state-default']/table/tr/td/span[@class='dijitIconFlag dijitFixedMatterIcon']")).click()
```

Option 2:

```
WebUiCommonHelper.findWebElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='dgrid-row dgrid-row-even ui-state-default']/table/tr/td[contains(@class,'dgrid-cell dgrid-cell-padding dgrid-column-0-')]").click()
```

Option3:

```
WebUI.click(findTestObject('Object Repository/Page_Law Practice Management Software  CosmoLex/td_Client Funds-Trust_dgrid-cell dgrid-cell_865aa6'))
```

## Source code:

Source code is in `xPath.jpg`.

## Expected:

The row should be selected/clicked.

[image: xPath]

[image: Error message]

Comment: Have you imported all the needed classes? E.g. `import org.openqa.selenium.By`?

Comment: Yes classes are imported

Comment: @Mate Mrse Now I am getting the following error with katalon studio :  Reason:
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.kms.katalon.core.webui.common.WebUiCommonHelper.findWebElement() is applicable for argument types: (org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath) values: [By.xpath: //div[@class='dgrid-row dgrid-row-even ui-state-default']/table/tr/td/span[@class='dijitIconFlag dijitFixedMatterIcon']]

Answer (score 0):

```
//table[@class="dgrid-row-table"]//tr//td
```

Use this as xpath,
and click by this manner.
Hope it will help you.

```
List<WebElement> objects = WebUiCommonHelper.findWebElements(findTestObject('***put xpath url here***'), 30)
WebUI.delay(1)
objects.get(0).click()
```

Comment: Now I am getting below error:org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
file:/C:/Users/DELL/Katalon%20Studio/SampleProject/Scripts/Common%20TestCases/Active%20Matter/Script1572862915310.groovy: 36: unable to resolve class WebElement 
 @ line 36, column 6.
   List<WebElement> objects = WebUiCommonHelper.findWebElements(findTestObject('//*[@id="dgrid_1-row-9cfecd21-e608-452d-9ffc-348bd9a8b695"]/table/tr/td[4]/span'), 30)
        ^

Comment: import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.common.WebUiCommonHelper

            add these two library in import section

Comment: Now I am getting below issue :2019-11-08 17:57:10.557 WARN  c.k.k.core.testobject.ObjectRepository   - Test object with id 'Object Repository///*[@id='dgrid-row-table']/table/tr/td' does not exist

Comment: please use this //table[@class="dgrid-row-table"]//tr//td as Xpath